# Clear an arraylist after return statement

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that returns an ArrayList. I want to clear or re-initialise the the array list after the return statement so that the old data is not repopulated. I know we can use arrayList.clear() statement but I am not sure where to place it in the code so that the re-initialization happens after returning the array list .

My code snippet :

```
public static List<HashMap<String, String>> GetDataIteration(String strDataSheetPath, String sTCID) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm;
    //List<Map<String, String>> hmList = new ArrayList();
    //List<HashMap<String, String>> hmList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {

            String sTestDataFile ="C:\\AutomationGoldCopy\\IEDSS_Automation\\src\\TestData\\Support\\Support_TC_001_AddUserBuildProfile1.xlsx";
            File file = new File(sTestDataFile);
            FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook wb = null;

            if (sTestDataFile.contains(".xlsx"))
            {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
            } else if (sTestDataFile.contains(".xls"))
            { 
              wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
            }

            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int count = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;

            System.out.println(count);
            for (int i=1 ; i <count ; i++)
            {   
                Row headerrow = sheet.getRow(0);
                hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                System.out.println(i);      
                Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < headerrow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) 
                {
                   Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(j,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);   
                   hm.put(headerrow.getCell(j).toString(), currentCell.toString());                
                }   
                //hmList.clear();
                hmList.add(hm); 

                for (HashMap<String, String> h : hmList) {
                    for (String key : h.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(key + "\t" + h.get(key));
                    }
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                // hmList.clear();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return hmList;

    }
```

Kindly help me with the same.

main method :

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String dtDataSheetPath = null;
    String dtTestCaseID = null;

    List<HashMap<String, String>> TestDataList = Excel.GetDataIteration(dtDataSheetPath,dtTestCaseID);
    for(Map<String, String> TestData : TestDataList) {

        String name = TestData.get("TestCase Name");
        String name1 = TestData.get("SMU_LastName");            
        System.out.println( "Got it : " + name + " " + name1);
    }
```

There are three rows in the excel . The first is the hearder row and the last two rows are the header values.
I am converting the excel rows into a hashmap with header row as keys and the second and third rows as values of the hashmap.

In the second run ( when i =2 ) , the first row is repopulated again. I just wanted the second row. When I clear the ArrayList hmList , it works fine but I wanted to return the list too.

Comment: As you can see in the different answers, it makes no sense to have `hmList` outside of the `GetDataIteration` method, when you want to clear it anyway and clearing the map, would also makes no sense.

Comment: Now with your revised code, your method does **NOT** return an ArrayList.  Please fix your question.

Comment: @SteveCohen *"your method does NOT return an ArrayList."* What does it return instead?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what it returns.  The declaration of hmList, the return value, is commented out.

Comment: @SteveCohen So you wanna prefer to say "your method does **MAYBE** return an ArrayList"?

Comment: @Tom My method returns an arrayList hmList. But it returns 3 rows ( consider that my excel contains 2 rows ). The first row is populated twice. I read somewhere that we need to clear the arrayList .

Comment: So you have an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to fix X with Y and you're asking us how to do Y. Instead you should ask us how to fix X properly. When it is populated twice, then you have a bug somewhere in your code and this should be treated. So please create an [mcve] of that problem and create a new question asking how to fix your main problem and post that small example.

Comment: @Tom Sorry , I am new at this. I have added the main method where I am using the method GetDataIteration.

Answer (score 4):

In your function the initialization `hmList = new ArrayList>();` creates a new empty `List` each time the function is called so **there is no need to clear it after the `return` statement** (which, anyway, is not possible in the same function).

Comment: actually, `hmList = new ArrayList>();`  it's a comment, AFAIK I cannot see `hmList` declaration, IMO seems `hmList` is now a class attribute... which will make `hmList.clear()` useful...

Comment: @m.aibin no, OP doesn't, creates a `Map`, but returns a `List` which seems a class attribute....

Comment: @JordiCastilla *"which will make `hmList.clear()` useful"* useful to show that `hmList` shouldn't be a field in the first place. And if OP tries to do something like `#populateHmListStep1()`, `#populateHmListStep2()` and `#populateHmListStep3()` (step 3 is `GetDataIteration`) [#], then it would be a huge code smell. Maybe OP can explain what he really tries to achieve here. ([#] This is the only scenario that requires `hmList` to be a field).

Comment: @Tom *useful to show that hmList* hahahaaha.... as long as I cannot see rest of the code, I cannot say that... agree we need further explanation and OP clarification, but just wanted to point, **this is not the answer OP is looking for...** at least, not now...

Answer (score -1):

As *hmList* seems to me a static variable you can return a copy of this list and clear the *hmList* before the return, if your specification says *hmList* should be empty by the return of your function.

Comment: but why? It will create additional not required object.

Comment: @m.aibin note that `hmList` is not a local variable within the method, but is more likely a static member variable of the class. If it the OP really has the requirement of clearing `hmList`, then this answer seems to be pretty correct.